# Run-time error in NetLogo, turtles trying to turn 'towards' but get NOBODY instead

Tags: netlogo

Massive favour to ask you all. I have one last bug to squash in my code and then it is done!

My aim with all this code is to move all the turtles if there is a vacant patch in neighbors4. The turtles that have a gap then a turtle after that anywhere in their neighbors4 get turned, either towards or away from that turtle after the gap, depending on the J value of the extended neighbours. All the other turtles move to another square on the neighbors4.

I am having a problem with turning the turtles. They usually are fine, except now and then I get an error saying the turtle was trying to turn towards NOBODY. I don't understand why this is happening, because as far as I can tell, only turtles with a gap and a turtle after are asked to turn, so they should always have a 'somebody' to turn towards.

The world has wrapping on. I also tried using 'carefully' to check what happened if I went past the error, and the 'face' gets the same error as well. Its probably something really simple but I just can't work it out.

```
     to go  
        ask turtles 
           [ move-turtle]
          tick
    end

    to move-turtle
      let vacant-patches neighbors4 with [not any? turtles-here ]  
      ifelse any? turtles with  [(count turtles at-points [ [ 0 2 ] ]  = 1 ) and 
(count turtles at-points  [ [ 0 1] ] = 0 )  
                          or (count turtles at-points [ [-2 0] ] = 1 ) and 
(count turtles at-points  [ [-1 0] ] = 0 ) 
                          or (count turtles at-points [ [2 0] ]  = 1 ) and 
(count turtles at-points [ [1 0] ] = 0 ) 
                          or (count turtles at-points [ [0 -2] ]  = 1 ) and 
(count turtles at-points [  [0 -1] ]= 0 ) ]                   
                     [turn-turtle 
                       if can-move? 1 and not any? turtles-on patch-ahead 1 
                       [move-to patch-ahead 1]] 
                     [ move-to one-of vacant-patches ]
      set JBB 0
      set JSS 0 ;;not sure if I need to do this either? 
        end

    to turn-turtle
      let target-heading 0                                         
      if any? bigs with     [(count bigs at-points  [[0 2]]  = 1 ) and 
(count turtles at-points [ [ 0 1]] = 0 ) 
                          or (count bigs at-points [[-2 0]]  = 1 ) and 
(count turtles at-points  [[-1 0] ]= 0 ) 
                          or (count bigs at-points [[2 0] ] = 1 ) and 
(count turtles at-points[ [1 0] ]= 0 ) 
                          or (count bigs at-points [[0 -2]]  = 1 ) and 
(count turtles at-points  [ [0 -1] ]= 0 ) ]
                          [ask bigs at-points [[0 2] [-2 0] [2 0] [0 -2]] [set JBB 0.7 ]]                                          
       if any? smalls with     [(count smalls at-points [ [ 0 2 ] ]  = 1 ) and 
(count turtles at-points  [ [ 0 1] ] = 0 ) 
                          or (count smalls at-points [ [-2 0] ] = 1 ) and 
(count turtles at-points  [ [-1 0] ] = 0 ) 
                          or (count smalls at-points [ [2 0] ]  = 1 ) and 
(count turtles at-points [ [1 0] ] = 0 ) 
                          or (count smalls at-points [ [0 -2] ]  = 1 ) and 
(count turtles at-points [  [0 -1] ]= 0 ) ]
                          [ask smalls at-points [[0 2] [-2 0] [2 0] [0 -2]] [set JSS 1.4 ]]                                         
    let joining-list (sentence (JBB) (JSS))
    let max-list max joining-list
    let min-list min joining-list
    let repellor min-one-of turtles at-points [[0 2] [-2 0] [2 0] [0 -2]]  [min joining-list] 
    let attractor max-one-of turtles at-points [[0 2] [-2 0] [2 0] [0 -2]] [ max joining-list]
    if min-list < 1
         [ set target-heading one-of [ 90 180 270 ]  + towards repellor   ;;this line has the error
           set heading target-heading]  
    if max-list > 1  
         [ face attractor] ] ;;and this line has the error
    end
```

The run-time error:

```
TOWARDS expected input to be an agent but got NOBODY instead.
error while bigs 1 running TOWARDS
  called by procedure TURN-TURTLE
  called by procedure MOVE-TURTLE
  called by procedure GO
  called by Button 'go'
```

Comment: Also, would it be any better to make the "turn-turtle" procedure a "to-report turtle-heading" procedure instead? Or not make any difference? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`turtles at-points [[0 2] [-2 0] [2 0] [0 -2]]` is reporting `no-turtles`; you have to decide what you want to do in this case.

Your question could be reinterpreted as a question about how to debug your code.  In this example, you could just place `print` or `show` commands in your code each time you make an assignment to look at what you actually go (like `print repellor` right after you assign to `repellor`).  In this case, it would have been a good idea to `let candidates turtles at-points [[0 2] [-2 0] [2 0] [0 -2]]` and then `print candidates` to see what turtle set you're getting.

Aside from your question, there are some other issues.  It is unlikely that your lines with `min-one-of` and `max-one-of` are doing what you intend.  Whenever you are actually working with a turtle set, these lines as currently written will just report a random turtle.  Here's why: `min-one-of` takes a reporter argument, for which you provide `[min joining-list]`.  But this is always reporting the same number, not a different number for each turtle.  You need to move the relevant code into a separate turtle reporter, so that the value is recomputed for each turtle in your turtle set.

Comment: Advice about adding print statements, seconded.

Comment: Thanks for the advice about how to debug, its been helpful @Alan and @SethTissue! I still haven't solved the problem yet though after playing around for a while. If the line 'let attractor max-one-of turtles at-points [[0 2] [-2 0] [2 0] [0 -2]] [ max-list]' is just choosing a random turtle, how do I write it to so that it assigns the turtle on the extended neighbours4 (at-points [[0 2] [-2 0] [2 0] [0 -2]])  with the max J value from the list(sentence)?

Comment: Actually I just changed it to 'ask bigs...' then 'ask smalls...' at the start of turn-turtle and I'm no longer getting there error woooo! Thanks so much for all your help. I think I still need to improve that line above, and my list sometimes has 6 entries when it should only ever get max 4, so a little bit more work to be done. Any ideas about the at-points question above? Thanks!

Comment: I'll elaborate in my answer.

Comment: Thanks so much @Alan, I changed it so the code asks one breed then the other breed and it works perfectly, thanks again!